# Good potted vine to grow inside a greenhouse?

Tags: containers, vines, greenhouse

I have a small greenhouse (9'x9' and 9' tall at peak) that I’d like to grow a vine inside and have it grow up through the exposed rafters. I think it would look very nice.

The vine species would:

- Have to be planted in a large pot and run up the wall since the greenhouse floor is finished with permeable pavers, i.e., it can’t be planted into the ground.
- Be able to handle the heat on a sunny day.
- Be at most moderate in its water requirements.
- Ideally be a species that flowers.

Any recommendations for vine species?

FYI: I’m in a temperate climate in the San Francisco Bay Area, so it never gets below freezing here.

Comment: I saw a potted wisteria in a greenhouse. Flowering and beautiful. It ran down a center rod in the green house; must have been 40 feet long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many fun climbing plants to choose from. ~

Morning Glory (Great for a variety of colors)

Moonflowers (the large, white blooms only open at night)

Climbing Hydrangea

Bougainvillea

Wisterias (these are very dramatic flowering vines)

I have grown most of those plants in large containers. I haven't grown the Climbing Hydrangeas myself but I have seen several people grow them successfully in large container pots.

Answer (score 0):

Jasmine might be excellent great effloration too, or climbing flowers might be good, either annuals or perennials, or, maybe some cherry tomatoes of a strain which just keeps growing, Jasmine & tomatoes grow well together; might be able to keep the tomatoes year round, and get some delicious tomatoes too: theyre quite atractive actually, and have nice little flowers, and the fruits are colourful: might need to pollinate them with a little brush if nothing there to pollinate them or little wind movement action

Comment: I currently have a tomato plant in my greenhouse that I've been pollinating with a small brush. So far, it seems to be working since tomatoes are starting to grow.